# Why would invokeAll() not return?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have roughly this code:

```
ExecutorService threader = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(queue.size());
List futures = threader.invokeAll(queue);
```

I debug this and invokeAll doesn't seem to return until all the threads in the Queue are finished.  Any reasons why this is happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. [the API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection))

You have to `submit()` them one at a time instead, something like:

```
public static <T> List<Future<T>> submitAll ( ExecutorService executor, Collection<? extends Callable<T> > tasks ) {
    List<Future<T>> result = new ArrayList<Future<T>>( tasks.size() );

    for ( Callable<T> task : tasks )
        result.add ( executor.submit ( task ) );

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because it's designed like that:

```
[...]
Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. 
[...]
```

is a quote from http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 2):

When we call `invokeAll()` method it returns `List<Futute<T>>` object.
And this `Future` object holds the value of all threads untill it is successfully executed.
So when we try to try to iterate through `Future<T>` object it first internally checks `Future<T>.isDone()` [We may or may not check `Future<T>.isDone()` externally]. If it returns true we can iterate through the object and can access the value of the `Future<T>` Object, else it waits until true.

Note: If `Future<T>` gets a false object it will not allow you to iterate through the object.

```
ExecutorService threader = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(queue.size());  
List<Future<T>> listFuture = threader.invokeAll(queue);  
for(Future<T> future: listFuture) {
    // Here you have the full access to this future object  
}
```